Why can the ContentDisposition in node's FormData correctly handle Chinese characters, but the ContentDisposition in C# becomes garbled?
Node ContentDisposition
Data chunk available: ----------------------------177469602625230163138256 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filenam"; filename="菜单别名.docx" Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
C# ContentDisposition
form-data; name="file"; filename="=?utf-8?B?6I+c5Y2V55qE56ys5LqMLmRvY3g=?="
Why can the ContentDisposition in node's FormData correctly handle Chinese characters, but the ContentDisposition in C# becomes garbled?
I tried using 'ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse' with Chinese characters directly, but they ended up as '?'.

I would say that node isn't doing this correctly. The header should be encoded if it contains characters outside of ISO-8859-1, preferably using  https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5987.txt but C#/.NET seems to be using the older https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt to accomplish the same thing.
